# listview onclick through xml

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

This is more of a theoretical question, I have searched in many places, but unable to find the answer:
If i add an android:onClick tag to my ListView inside the layout file, what is the method signature I should use for my java Activity in order to correctly have it been called?

```
<ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:entries="@array/models"
            android:onClick="getSpecs">

</ListView>
```

Comment: This tag means click on the listView itself, not the items of the listview. The Java code looks exactly like a button's onClick

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @code-apprentice I was mostly curious if that was possible at all, i just like simple solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Java method signature, but it will be fired everytime you click *anywhere* in the ListView. It is **not** an ItemClickListener, as I assume that was your intention for that XML.

```
public void getSpecs(View v) {

}
```

Note that the `android:onClick` XML attribute is the same as `View#setOnClickListener`, meaning it sets the generalized view's click listener. For buttons and such this is fine, but ListViews and other complex, nested views, there are other interfaces for catching the appropriate clicks.

Comment: Note that this is the same signature for any `onClick` method no matter what kind of view it is attached to.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Got it

Comment: What I had in mind is that `onClick` is the same whether it is for a `<Button>` or anything else. In other words, the examples which describe how `onClick` works for `<Button>` apply equally well to `<ListView>`. (I'm sure you know this. I'm just clarifying for the OP and future readers.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know that was whats going on when i use the attribute, it all makes sense now